# What is wrong in this Perl regex in OSX?

Tags: bash, perl

The [code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126293/16920) works in Ubuntu, but not in OSX.

I run

```
perl -000pe 's/\n/\n\\begin{enumerate}\n/; s/\n\d./\n\\item /g; s/$/\\end{enumerate}\n/' lorem.tex
```

I get

```
-bash: $: command not found
MacBook-Air:draft masi$
```

Comment: On perl 5 v12 I'v no problems with your script.

Comment: What does `perl -v` give?

Comment: @Mark "This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level".

Comment: Your shell prompt chanegs what are $PS1 and $PS2 ?

Comment: @Mark echo $PS1: \h:\W \u\$. echo $PS2: > (only arrow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you might have cut-n-pasted the command in to the shell in some odd way - or you manually entered it in the wrong way.

Try again, and this time pay attention to the quote characters. You need to use the right apostrophes. Make sure you don't use backticks or similar.

Comment: This is strange. I paste the same thing to my Zsh prompt and everything works. I paste the thing to Bash prompt and  I get this error. I think Zsh understands those marks (',") more extended.

Comment: It's not more strange than it works when I paste it in my bash shell. You need to check those quotation marks when you paste it in. Try _typing_ it in instead!